# Add parameters from one array of objects to enother by identifier

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects:

```
`let arr1 = [
{"var1":1, "id": 1},
{"var2":2, "id": 2},
{"var3":3, "id": 3}]

`let arr2 = [
{"someVal":1, "data":123, "id": 1},
{"someVal":2, data":456, "id": 2}]
```

I need to add in to objects in 'arr1' parameters `someVal` from objects in `arr2` by `id's`.
Result should be

```
 `let arr1 = [
    {"var1":1, "id": 1, "someVal":1},
    {"var2":2, "id": 2, "someVal":1},
    {"var3":3, "id": 3}]
```

Comment: Several ways to do this. Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is to help fix your code when it doesn't work as expected, not do all the work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```js
const arr1 = [{"var1":1,"id":1},{"var2":2,"id":2},{"var3":3,"id":3}],
      arr2 = [{"someVal":1,"id":1},{"someVal":2,"id":2}]

      result = arr1.map(o => {
        const someVal = arr2.find(({id}) => o.id == id)?.someVal
        return {...o, ...(someVal ? {someVal} : {})}
      })
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: @Ted : is there anything wrong about how this code works for you making you hesitate while accepting/un-accepting?

Comment: not actually merge, just insert one parameter from object, updated question

Comment: @Ted : now it seems to provide exactly your expected output

Answer (score 1):

You could use two `forEach` loops to add the corresponding values to `arr1`.

```js
let arr1 = [
{"var1":1, "id": 1},
{"var2":2, "id": 2},
{"var3":3, "id": 3}]

let arr2 = [
{"someVal":1, "id": 1},
{"someVal":2, "id": 2}]

arr1.forEach(elem_arr1 => {
  arr2.forEach(elem_arr2 => {
    if(elem_arr1.id == elem_arr2.id){
      elem_arr1["someVal"]= elem_arr2.someVal
    }
  })
})

console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1.forEach((element) => {
  arr2.map(item => {
    if(element.id == item.id)
      element.someVal = item.someVal;
  })
});
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `forach` and `object.assign` to achieve this

```js
let arr1 = [{"var1":1, "id": 1},{"var2":2, "id": 2},{"var3":3, "id": 3}]
let arr2 = [{"someVal":1, "data":123, "id": 1},{"someVal":2, "data":456, "id": 2}]

  
  arr1.forEach(o=>{arr2.forEach(y=>{ if(o.id==y.id) Object.assign(o,y)})})
  console.log(arr1)
```